# Can't understand why a simple if-else statement is not printing words in html title tag

Tags: php, include

I am new to php, and can't figure out what to search for to describe this problem:

I have a page and it has:

```
$metatitle = "My page title";
```

In the header file that is being included:

```
if($metatitle == ''){
    $metatitle = "Some generic title"; 
}
```

and...

```
<title><?php echo $metatitle;?></title>
```

Now, the page is showing the "Some generic title" so I know it's working somewhat, but it's ignoring the fact that I have indeed put some text in that page.

PHP Version 5.2.17

---

**SOLVED:**  Thanks for the speedy answers though! I got it working by adding an else statement:

```
else {
    $metatitle;
}
```

BTW, this was someone else code--pretty bad mistake coming from an actual programmer

P.S.  Had to edit the question cause stackoverflow wouldn't let me answer my own question so soon.

Comment: Try printing out the content of `$metatitle` right before the `if` statement, see the output.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have them out of order. If you include the header file, and then declare the variable $metatitle, it's running the if block and printing out the title tags before it ever gets down to the variable. Place the variable declaration before the include(header.php) statement, like so:

```
$metatitle = "Current page";
include_once("includes/header.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your if condition is inside a function or if the echo is inside a function then you need to declare

```
global $metatitle;
```

inside the function.